# \textsc not working after \renewcommand

Tags: macros, small-caps

I recently fond a nice document template ([here](https://github.com/jrk/uggedal-thesis)) andI would like to use it for my thesis. However, the template uses the following line to change the default font for small capitals text:

```
\renewcommand{\scdefault}{ssc}
```

Then the `\textsc` command is used in the preambule to modify the appearance of `\chapter` and it works fine.

The problem is that anywhere in the text, if I try to use the `\textsc` command (or the `\lettrine` command), it does not transform the text in small caps. When I remove the `\renewcommand` line it work fine again, but the chapter does not look as I want.

Am I forgetting something?

Here is the code of my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english, makeindex, oneside]{memoir} \usepackage{lettrine}

% New commands 
\renewcommand{\scdefault}{ssc} 
\newcommand{\uppercaps}[1]{\textsc{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}

% Style for chapters
\makechapterstyle{newchap}{
\renewcommand{\printchaptername}{}
\renewcommand{\chapternamenum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\afterchapternum}{}
\renewcommand{\printchaptertitle}[1]{
\raggedright\huge\uppercaps{##1}
}}

\begin{document} \chapterstyle{newchap}

\chapter{First chapter}

\lettrine{T}{his is a lettrine} and this and 
this is supposed to be in \textsc{small caps font}


\end{document}
```

And here is the output with the `\renewcommand`

[image]

And here is the output without the `\renewcommand`

[image]

I am using pdfLaTex and the `memoir` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well you don't have definitions for the shape "ssc" so LaTeX falls back to standard cmr: The `\textsc` in the title and in the document doesn't do anything.

So you probably should drop the `\renewcommand\scdefault` and use simply `\MakeUppercase` instead of `\uppercaps` in `\makechapterstyle`.

Comment: Just as a remark: the spaced small caps ``ssc`` shape is provided by the ``MinionPro`` package which is loaded by the template.

Comment: You may want to use letterspacing (`\textls`) from package `microtype` or `letterspace` to achieve _spacing_ in small caps.